# How to copy content of a numpy matrix to another?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a simple question about basics of `python` and `numpy` module. I have a function as following:

```
def update_x_last(self, x):
    self.x_last = x
```

The class attribute x_last and function argument x are both initialized as of type `numpy.matrix` and of the same shape. (`x.shape = x_last.shape = (4,1`)

I have noticed that the code above does not copy the content of the argument `x` to `x_last`, but it makes the object `x_last` point to the address of `x`.

However what I want to do is the following:

- Don't change the address of `self.x_last`
- Copy only the content of `x` to `self.x_last`

What is the best way to do this?

**Edit:**
the requirement 'Don't change the address of 'self.x_last' was unimportant for me. The only required behaviour is the second requirement to copy only the content.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to change the address of `self.x_last`?

Comment: @MooingRawr: Yes, I call the update function on specific conditions. Lets say every 2 seconds, 0,2,4... But the time passes every 1 seconds, 0,1,2.... I only want to update x_last every 2 seconds but I realised it has the updated value at odd seconds, even though the function is not called. 
P.S: The argument x is another object stored somewhere else, not a matrix that I generate at every function call.

Comment: @OnurA: I don't see how that is an answer to the question. Let's phrase it differently: Why would if not work if `id(x_last)` changed each time?

Comment: @Eric: you are right, I got the question wrong that's why my answer was also irrelevant. The only important thing is that self.x_last shouldn't be changed if x continues to change. As you mention below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the shapes are the same, then any of these meet both of your requirements:

```
self.x_last[...] = x
# or self.x_last[()] = x
# or self.x_last[:] = x
```

I'd argue that the first one is probably most clear

---

Let's take a look at your requirements quickly:

> Copy only the content of x to self.x_last

Seems reasonable. This means if that if `x` continues to change, then `x_last` won't change with it

> Don't change the address of `self.x_last`

This doesn't buy you anything. IMO, this is actively worse, because functions using `x_last` in another thread will see it change underneath them unexpectedly, and worse still, could work with the data when it is incompletely copied from `x`

Comment: what is the difference between [...] and [:] ?

Comment: `...` means _"as many `:`s as needed to match the array dimension"_. The difference only really matters if `x` is 0-dimensional: `x = np.array(1); x[:]` is an error, but `x = np.array(1); x[...]` is not.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

self.x_last = np.copy(x)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the _"Don't change the address of self.x_last"_ that the question imposed